# Treeview deleting parent if currentnode child being deleted is the last child

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I can't get the parent node of "current_node" deleted from my Tree. Here is what I am trying:
I am developing in C# .NET for VSTO

```
TreeGridNode current_node = myTreeGrid.CurrentNode;
TreeGridNode parent_node = myTreeGrid.CurrentNode.Parent;
// this works
myTreeGrid.Nodes.Remove(current_node);

if (parent_node.Nodes.Count == 0) {
    // it never gets here, it doesn't detect that the lats child was just removed above
    myTreeGrid.Nodes.Remove(parent_node);
}
```

using this custom structure
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markrideout/archive/2006/01/08/510700.aspx

Comment: What is the `TreeGridNode` class? Windows Forms?

Comment: edited: It's basically a TreeNode

Comment: Oh, so it's ASP.NET? Or was that Silverlight?

Comment: I'm using C# .NET (VSTO)

Comment: C# supports ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight and many other kinds of program. "TreeNode" is a very generic name for a class. What is the full name of the "TreeNode" class? What kind of application is this? Windows Forms?

Comment: Does `myTreeGrid.Nodes.Remove` search for `current_node` recursively?  Or does it just try to remove from the first level of siblings inside of `myTreeGrid.Nodes`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I think this is a custom class that the OP wrote, or some other generic data structure.  Not necessarily an element in a UI framework.

Comment: @MikeC: in that case, his answer is even more important, since it means nobody can answer his question without seeing this class and its related classes.

Comment: MikeC, JohnSaunders, I've edited the question with the custom class in use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your problem here is that you are trying to remove `current_node` from `myTreeGrid` and not `current_node`'s parent.  `myTreeGrid.Nodes` does not contain a reference to `current_node`, so calling `myTreeGrid.Nodes.Remove(current_node)` essentially does nothing.

Since nothing is ever removed, `parent_node.Nodes` still contains the reference to `current_node`.  Try removing `current_node` directly from `parent_node.Nodes` and your issue will probably be resolved:

**Change:**

```
myTreeGrid.Nodes.Remove(current_node);
```

to

```
parent_node.Nodes.Remove(current_node);
```